# Get array param from query in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt.js (Nuxt version is 2)
I have query params on my page `https://localhost:9000/applicant?period_manual[]=2022-10-09&period_manual[]=2022-10-19`

I need to get `period_manual` params from query.

If I trying to do

```
console.log(this.$route.query.period_manual) //- It is undefined
console.log(this.$route.query) //- this outputs {period_manual[]: ["2022-10-16", "2022-10-25"]} 
console.log(this.$route.query.period_manual[]) //- ESLint error - ESLint: Parsing error: An element access expression should take an argument
```

How I can get data of period_manual[] from query request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to that one

```js
this.$route.query['period_manual[]']
```